# Поиск символов 1 массива во 2 и добавление в 3 массив

Tags: python

Почему такой код не работает?

```
a = []   
ch = []
otr = []
s = input()
for i in s:
    a.append(i)
for i in range(0,10):
    ch.append(i)
na = len(a)
nch = len(ch)

for i in range(na):
    for k in range(nch):
        if a[i] == ch[k]:
           otr.append(a[i])
print(otr)
```

В массиве a будут и цифры и буквы, надо чтобы оттуда вытащили все цифры и они ушли в массив otr (массив ch содержит цифры). И это не работает, что делать? Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод `isdigit()`. И не нужно перебирать полученную строку, так как переменная типа `string` , полученная в методе `input()` является итерируемой переменной и ее можно перебирать, как список (list).

Код существенно сократится:

```
otr = []
s = input()
for i in s:
    if i.isdigit():
        otr.append(i)
print(otr)
```

Вывод:

```
C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\@tmp\04>python 01.py
dd123ff2dr3r4;5
['1', '2', '3', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2):

*Не касаясь самого алгоритма и т.п.*

Конкретно здесь проблема в строчке `if a[i] == ch[k]:`. Здесь сравнивается строка с числом и такое сравнение никогда не даст положительный результат. Если изменить на

```
if a[i] == str(ch[k]):
```

то все будет работать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало)))